# How to configure Gradle module name in InteliJ IDEA

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, subproject

I have project with numerous of submodules located in different directories:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwFjy.png)

How you can see, the module name of IDEA (in []) differs from directory root. I've tried to modify it though `Project Settings`, but after gradle sync it returns to initial state.

Is it possible to configure Gradle to set module name according with directory name?

Answer (score 1):

IDE takes the module name from the Gradle configuration, which is by default a project directory name. If you want to change it you can do so by adding the following in the `settings.gradle` file:

```
rootProject.name = 'newProjectName'
```

See also the [Naming recommendations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#naming_recommendations) from Gradle.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to set module name as directory name? (`core` instead of `air-ndc-directconnect-service.core`)